# jquery checkbox issue - reload page fixes it

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems with this bit of jquery. When the page loads, id_2 is hidden. If I check the check box id_1 nothing happens. However if I reload the page, id_2 then shows.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">  /script>
</head>


<input id="id_1" type="checkbox" name="ck1">
<input type="text" id="id_2" name="tx1">

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             if ($('#id_1').is(':checked'))  {
                 ($('#id_2').show());
             } else {
                 ($('#id_2').hide());
             }
});
```

If I use a button and

```
$("#show_button").click(function()
```

it works - id_2 shows/hides correctly. I can see in firebug that when I check the checkbox the checked value toggles from true / false.

What am I doing wrong?

Oli

Comment: there are syntax problems with your `script` tag

Comment: Hi. I have fixed that up but still no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have an event handler. You are checking to see if the checkbox is checked on page load, so if you check it and refresh the page, your browser remembers that the checkbox is checked, and thus the event is fired on page reload (showing `#id_2`)

If you want it to be dynamic, with no page reload necessary, add an event handler (e.g., click):

```
$('#id_1').click(function(){
    if ($('#id_1').is(':checked')){
         $('#id_2').show();
    } else {
         $('#id_2').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the answer I followed. I have been banging my head against this, but it now works.. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your logic inside a `click` or `change` event, otherwise you're just hiding / showing according the value that comes from the server.

Also change

```
if ($('#id_1').is('checked'))
```

By

```
if ($('#id_1').is(':checked'))
```

And as other user remarked (not sure if it's a typo when pasting the code here), your jquery reference has syntax errors. Change it by this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: I have fixed up what you suggested. I have actually tried this before but the text field only displays after a reload..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_2').css('display', $('#id_1').is(':checked') ? 'block' : 'none');

    $('#id_1').change(function(){
        $('#id_2').css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none')
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I managed to fix this by adding the $('#id_1').click(function(){

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="id_1" type="checkbox" name="ck1">
<input type="text" id="id_2" name="tx1" style="display:none;">

<script>
$('#id_1').change(function(){
    if ($('#id_1').is(':checked'))  {
        $('#id_2').show();
    } else {
        $('#id_2').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

​

Comment: instead of .change, I used .click. Maybe this would have worked too.